# Looking for specific tokens involved in coref instances - Spacy and Neuralcoref

Tags: python, spacy

I am looking for an appropriate way to look for instances where specific pronouns have been used in coreference instances in some documents I am looking at. One I am having problems with memory, which makes me think I am not doing it in a very economic way, but I am also not sure if I am going about it in the right way. The idea is to identify all instances of it and they in coreference instances for the moment, but I may want to extend this. I then want to go on to replace all these instances with the head word of coreference.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
import spacy
import neuralcoref
import en_coref_md
import os

nlp_en = en_coref_md.load()
path = './input_zenodo/'
filelist = os.listdir(path)

for file in filelist:
    try:
        file = open(path+file).read()
        doc = nlp_en(file)
        is_pronoun = 'it' 
    except MemoryError:
        print('MemoryError:'+file+'\n')  

    for token in doc:
        if token.text == is_pronoun:
                print(token._.in_coref)
                print(token._.coref_clusters)
```

If anyone can give advice as to potentially more economical ways of doing this, or advice as to how to replace only these coreference clusters in a document I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to replace each reference with its head, there's a built-in `coref_resolved` attribute for this in `neuralcoref`:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_coref_lg')
text = "Rufus is my dog. He is a good boy."
doc = nlp(text)

print(doc._.coref_resolved)
```

returns

```
"Rufus is my dog. Rufus is a good boy."
```

The code that implements it is [here](https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref/blob/633aeade988505306f484e966e62f5d9a2d4364d/neuralcoref/neuralcoref.pyx#L262), and this seems like the place to modify it if you really would only like to resolve pronouns, and not all corefs.